# Android: Turn screen dark but don't allow screen lock

Tags: android, screen, android-wake-lock, android-windowmanager

I want to turn screen dark on user inactivity (to save battery) but don't want to allow screen lock.

I have used following code to not allow screen lock when my application is running:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Then when inactivity is detected I use the following code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=1.0f; 
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

But this doesn't work. I have also tried using `lp.screenBrightness = 0f;` but that only reduces brightness and doesn't make the screen dark.